# How to create android notification styled like Whatsapp or Telegream using Notification.setStyle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications, android-notification.mediastyle

How to create android notification styled like Whatsapp or Telegream chat notification using Notification.setStyle(Notification.MessagingStyle) or any other without using remoteviews

[image]

i could get that using Notification.CallStyle but i see hangup button which i don't want or customise the button text,icon,color

[image]

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            Person.Builder personBuilder = new Person.Builder();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.angry_bird);
            Icon icon = Icon.createWithBitmap(bitmap);
            personBuilder.setIcon(icon);
            personBuilder.setName("It's Me");
            personBuilder.setImportant(true);
            Person person = personBuilder.build();
            Notification.CallStyle style = Notification.CallStyle.forOngoingCall(person,pendingIntent);
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(style);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText("Hello");
        }
```

Comment: not found any yet